# Filter in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a txt file with generated from a fantasy sport side: this is how it looks:

```
team: Sharks
status: playing
date: 2016/03/11

team: Sharks
status: playing
date: 2016/03/11

team: Sharks
status: not playing
date: 2016/03/12
```

So every team , status and date are displayed bear in mind there are more then does that I posted so not only the sharks play

MORE THAN ONE TEAM CAN PLAY ON THE SAME DATE

Anyway I would like to sort that out so to have a team appear once as well as their status and date playing or not something like that

```
team Sharks
status:playing
date playing:
2016/03/11
2016/03/11
date not playing:
2016/03/12And yes I tried do something with removing the duplicates but that does notv really work / not the result as expected

Dim nextPlace As Long
Dim maxRows As Long

Sub walkThePlank()
maxRows = 10000                'UPDATE THIS AS NEEDED
nextPlace = 3

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = "team:"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = "status:"


findData ("status: playing")
addToNextSpace ("Status: Not playing")
findData ("status: not playing")

End Sub

Sub findData(s As String)
Dim i As Long

Dim isPlaying As Boolean
isPlaying = False

For i = 1 To 1000

If isPlaying Then
    addToNextSpace (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value)
End If


If LCase(Range("A" & i).Value) = s Then
    isPlaying = True
Else
    isPlaying = False
End If


Next i

End Sub


Sub addToNextSpace(s As String)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & nextPlace).Value = s
nextPlace = nextPlace + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using VBA it would be easier to add three columns (team | status | date) to the right with the following formulas (for the example I assume that 'team: Sharks' is in cell A1):

1st column =IF(LEFT(A1,4)="team",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"team: ",""),"")
2nd column: =IF(LEFT(A1,4)="team",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"status: ",""),"")
3rd column: =IF(LEFT(A1,4)="team",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"date: ",""),"")

Then drag the formulas down and add a filter to delete the empty rows and to sort by team or whatever you want. Of course you can automate this with VBA. Macro reader should work for that.